# Load many font variations in QML

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I have a QtQuick/QML 5.6 project where I need to load 45 `.ttf` files representing weight variations of different (related) font families.

For example, here is a subset of the font files (three weights for two families):

- EncodeSans-Thin.ttf
- EncodeSans-Regular.ttf
- EncodeSans-Bold.ttf
- EncodeSansNarrow-Thin.ttf
- EncodeSansNarrow-Regular.ttf
- EncodeSansNarrow-Bold.ttf

I have added all 45 `.ttf` files to a `.qrc` in my project, but when I try to use the font family, it does not work:

```
Text { text:"So Thin"; font.family:"Encode Sans"; font.weight:Font.Thin }
Text { text:"Fatty";   font.family:"Encode Sans"; font.weight:Font.Bold }
```

<strike>If I add a *single* font loader for one font in each family, however, it works, for all weight variations of that font</strike>

```
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/EncodeSans-Regular.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/EncodeSansNarrow-Regular.ttf" }
Text { text:"So Thin"; font.family:"Encode Sans"; font.weight:Font.Thin }
Text { text:"Fatty";   font.family:"Encode Sans"; font.weight:Font.Bold }
```

<strike>I am surprised by this. It certainly appears to be using `EncodeSans-Thin.ttf` for the thin weight and `EncodeSans-Bold.ttf` for the bold weight, despite never mentioning those files in any `FontLoader`.</strike>

**Edit: the above code does NOT work. Due to a separate bug I now know that `Font.Thin` was never working (was showing the Regular weight), and it's possible that bold was being simulated by the text renderer.**

Am I supposed to add 45 `FontLoader` to my project, one for each TTF? Or is there a way to get all the TTF to be loaded with no need for `FontLoader`?

Comment: Or just do it in C++? `QDirIterator it(":/fonts/*.ttf"); while (it.hasNext()) QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(it.next());`

Comment: @peppe Thanks for the code, that may be helpful. I'd prefer to stick with pure QML however.

Comment: As you may see in my answer to your other qml font related question I would say above suggestion is a way to go, so unfortunately pure QML font support is in most of cases unresolvable pain...

Comment: @Phrogz: I am now in the same situation, did you figure this out using QML?

Comment: @Phataas I simply added 45 `FontLoader` instances to my project, one for each TTF.

Comment: @Phrogz: And then do you set the `font.family` or set the `weight` property?

Comment: `FontLoader { id:normalFont; source:"qrc:…" } … Text { font.family: normalFont.name; styleName: 'Thin' }` — You need one id for each family variation (which all share the same `.name`), and then you need to set the `weight` (or `styleName`  to work around [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37573849/405017) for Qt 5.6.1 or 5.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
Repeater {
    id: repeater
    property var fontList: [] // e.g. Qt.resolvedUrl("qrc:///fonts/EncodeSans-Regular.ttf"), or load a list from resource/config files
    model: ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }
    FontLoader {
        source: model.source
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 0; i < fontList.length; i++) {
            listModel.append({ source: fontList[i] })
        }
    }
}
```

edit: Given a list of strings and URLs you can use a repeater to load many fonts.  Component.onCompleted: the script reads the list of URLS to load fonts from, and adds all of them to the list.  Since the repeater model is a ListModel, the repeater will create new items when added to ListModel.  Repositioning is also available to repeaters this way, but not used here.
Note: Loading the list of URLs is not given in this snippet.

Comment: Please explain how this code answers the OP's questions: "_Am I supposed to add 45 FontLoader to my project, one for each TTF? Or is there a way to get all the TTF to be loaded with no need for FontLoader?_". Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: In FontLoader, where does `source: model.source` come from? I am trying to understand it with reference to QML documentation and I don't see this `source` property on model mentioned anywhere.