# QML not using Thin font weight

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I have a QML app using the freely-available [Encode Sans font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/encode-sans), which comes in 9 weights that match [Qt 5.6's font weights](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-font.html).

I have added all .ttf to my project, and am using a `FontLoader` to load them. Everything works perfectly, except for the Thin weight of the font.

In addition to the code below I have tried providing a unique `id` on the FontLoader for Thin, to ensure that the family name is the same (it is). How can I debug this problem and get Thin working?

[image: Screenshot of all weights being used. The Thin weight is listed first, and shows the same result as the Normal weight. All other weights vary as expected and look correct.]

```qml
### main.qml
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-Thin.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-ExtraLight.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-Light.ttf" }
FontLoader { id:mainFont; source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-Regular.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-Medium.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-SemiBold.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-Bold.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-ExtraBold.ttf" }
FontLoader { source:"qrc:/fonts/encodesans/EncodeSans-Black.ttf" }

Column {
  TextLine { weight:"Thin"       }
  TextLine { weight:"ExtraLight" }
  TextLine { weight:"Light"      }
  TextLine { weight:"Normal"     }
  TextLine { weight:"Medium"     }
  TextLine { weight:"DemiBold"   }
  TextLine { weight:"Bold"       }
  TextLine { weight:"ExtraBold"  }
  TextLine { weight:"Black"      }
}
```

```qml
### TextLine.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Text {
  property string weight

  text: "1 2 3 4 font.weight: Font."+weight
  color:"white"
  font {
    weight: Font[weight]
    family: mainFont.name
    pixelSize: 36
  }
}
```

<sub>*Using Qt 5.6 on Ubuntu, if it matters.*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Qt bug : [[QTBUG-53196] Thin fonts do not work in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53196)

One workaround you could use is using the [`styleName` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#font.styleName-prop) instead wich was introduced in Qt 5.6 .
The disadvantage of this method is that if you have some embedded bold in your text (with html or rich text), it won't work (if I understand this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51335) correctly).

You can use it like this :

```
### TextLine.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Text {
  property string weight

  text: "1 2 3 4 font.weight: Font."+weight
  color:"white"
  font {
    styleName: weight
    family: mainFont.name
    pixelSize: 36
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming the bug, and especially for the `styleName` workaround!